# Copy all folders contained in list from directory to another folder

Tags: python, directory, copy, shutil

I want to copy all folders which are summed up in a list from one directory to another folder.
The list contains the relevant names of the folders.
Now i want to copy the relevant ones into a new folder.

I am working with python and tried this issue with shutil.

My code doesnt copy anything and has no output.

Update:
It copies all data inside the subfolders, but not the folders.

This is my list:
[19116, 19118, 19131, 19146, 19119, 19164, 19166, 19180, 19168]

```
source_dir = input_folder_shp
dest_dir = folder_kgs
folders = kg_code_list

for i in os.listdir(source_dir):
    fold = os.path.join(source_dir, i)
    for f in folders:    
        f = str(f)
        if fold.endswith(f):
            if os.path.isdir(fold):
                shutil.copytree(fold, dest_dir, dirs_exist_ok=True)
```

Comment: You are currently just iterating through the folder name, which is just iterating through the characters that make up the string. If you want to iterate through the files/folders in that folder, you want something like `os.listdir(source_dir)`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os

source_dir = r"C:\folders\project\old"
dest_dir = r"C:\folders\project\new"
folders = kg_code_list

for file in os.listdir(source_dir):
    if file in folders:
        shutil.copytree(file, dest_dir)
        print(file)
```

This should wore. Before, you were just iterating through source_dir as a string, now you ask os to get all the files in the directory as a list, and go through that list.

Comment: unfortunately copy function is still not working. Also i get no answer from the print request.

Comment: Hmmm. os.listdir definitely works and will list the files in your directory. Try printing out all the items in listdir and see if you get the correct files. Likely your problem is the if statement, which means your list, folders stores filenames differently to os.listdir

Comment: The thing is, the code from above now copies all the data within the subfolders and not the folders itself.